# nginx: location = / {} error

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

My nginx vhost  config content:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name t.xianzhi.xxx.domain;
    access_log /data/log/nginx/t.xianzhi.xxx.domain_access.log main;

    location ~ /\. {deny  all;}

    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;

    location = / {
        root /data/web/static/html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        root /data/web/static/;
    }

    location = /apple-app-site-association {
        add_header Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        root /data/web/show/public/wap/;
    }

    location ~ \.(css|js|png|jpg|woff|ttf)$ {
        root /data/web/static;
        expires 10d;
    }

}
```

As the config, I want to server the path `/` to `/data/web/static/html/index.html` and server the others to proxy_pass.

The truth is the path `/` is 404 not found and the others is successful.

The log is :

```
24/Aug/2017:10:49:43 +0800  10.5.17.37  t.xianzhi.xxx.domain    -   curl/7.51.0 -   request:GET / HTTP/1.1  bbs:233status:404   upad:127.0.0.1:9000 rspt:0.017  rqtt:0.017  request_body:-
```

So, the `/` is passed to proxy.

Some info:

The nginx version: `nginx/1.10.1`

So, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `= /` location block. If you consider the section

```
location = / {
    root /data/web/static/html;
    index index.html;
}
```

You specify the root and index.html, but you don't server anything. So you should change it to

```
location = / {
    root /data/web/static/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

or

```
location = / {
    root /data/web/static/html;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: I tried this.  The good message is `/` path now is matched here. And the bad message is still 404;  For distinction， my config is ` try_files index.html =502;` . It return 502.  And I can confirm the file ` /data/web/static/html/index.html` is existing.

Comment: Let me confirm something if that block will even get called or not

Comment: So `=` block does get called. Check if my edits help

Comment: Ahh don't know what I was thinking using `./`